# How track an app installation not only from google play store

Tags: java, android, url, installation, tracking

I see that tracking apps installation using play store install referrer works only when apps intalled from play store. But how can we track all installation from other links (like Adjust install tracker)?

My attempt:

- Retrieve user `ip` at the moment redirect him to direct link.
- After installation and first open, retreive ip again and search for any match.

Issue : user's ip may change!

PS: we don't have access to apks download from markets, to edit apk on fly and add some files to assets. All markets and direct links have same apk file.

Comment: Check this out https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/, it allows you to generate links to track user installation.

Comment: I know that . `Branch` , `Adjust` and some other similar SDKs are available for this purpose . As i mentioned above , my Question is how do these SDKs works ?!